# Check out one Subversion file with Ant

Tags: svn, ant

How can I check out 1 file from a folder in SVN?

I found something called [Sparse Directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) but how to use it in Ant? I have several huge files in SVN, but I want to check out only one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out a directory but not a file . How ever you can use

```
svn export
```

to download a file

```
eg: svn export https://my.server.net/svn/myproject/build.xml
```

this will download build.xml to your local machine

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html

Coming to second part . Sparse Directory can be used to check out sub folders in your project .